# Unique IDs while using jQuery to append HTML Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, unique-id

I have an HTML form where I append some HTML objects using jQuery to keep the code clean(ish).

```
<span id="object_1"></span><span id="anotherobject_1"></span>
<span id="object_2"></span><span id="anotherobject_2"></span>
```

(in total there is seven of these "object - anotherobject"-constructs)

I append a simple text input and a select box seven times:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
$("#object_" + i).append("\
<input style='display: inline; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;  height: 15px; width:25px;' type='text'>");

$("#anotherobject_" + i).append("\
            <select style='display: inline; margin-left:  margin-top: -10px; width:45px;'>\
                    <option value='1'>1</option>\
                    <option value='2'>2</option>\
                    <option value='3'>3</option>\
                    <option value='4'>4</option>\
                    <option value='5'>5</option>\
                    <option value='6'>6</option>\
                    <option value='7'>7</option>\
                    <option value='8'>8</option>\
                </select>");

}
```

So now my problem is, if I gave the two objects an ID inside the javascript, I end up with seven objects having the same ID, that's a problem of course if I try to get access to their specific values... what can I do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can just create the id values using the `i` increment the same as you create the selector to find the item you are appending to.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/fx59aozv/

Comment: Why do you need IDs then? You can access dom elements in various ways including `:nth-child()` selector, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $("#object_" + i).append("\
         <input id='txt_"+i+"' style='display: inline; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;  height: 15px; width:25px;' type='text'>");

$("#anotherobject_" + i).append("\
            <select id='select_"+i+"' style='display: inline; margin-left:  margin-top: -10px; width:45px;'>\ 
                    <option value='1'>1</option>\
                    <option value='2'>2</option>\
                    <option value='3'>3</option>\
                    <option value='4'>4</option>\
                    <option value='5'>5</option>\
                    <option value='6'>6</option>\
                    <option value='7'>7</option>\
                    <option value='8'>8</option>\
                </select>");
}
```

Just use the `i`  value you are referring to get each `object` and `anotherobject`

You can simply do it as below using `$.each` too

```
$.each($("span[id^='object_']"),function(key){
    $(this).append("<input id='txt_"+key+"' style='display: inline; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;  height: 15px; width:25px;' type='text'>");
});

$.each($("span[id^='anotherobject_']"),function(key){
          $(this).append("<select id='select_"+key+"' style='display: inline; margin-left:  margin-top: -10px; width:45px;'>\ 
                        <option value='1'>1</option>\
                        <option value='2'>2</option>\
                        <option value='3'>3</option>\
                        <option value='4'>4</option>\
                        <option value='5'>5</option>\
                        <option value='6'>6</option>\
                        <option value='7'>7</option>\
                        <option value='8'>8</option>\
             </select>");
});
```

`span[id^='anotherobject_']` will select all the `span`s whose `id` begins with `anotherobject_` and same goes for `span` with `id` that starts with `object_`

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @Muellllkreis.. I have updated answer with more elegant way using `jquery`'s `$.each`.. Try that too.. Anyways.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [create an element with attrbutes in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) using a JSON object passed as the second parameter to make the code more readable.

You can then also set the id after the element is created.

```
var input_attr = { style: 'display: inline; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;  height: 15px; width:25px;', type: 'text' };
var select_attr = { style: 'display: inline; margin-left:  margin-top: -10px; width:45px;';
var options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

  $("#object_" + i).append(
    $('<input>', input_attr).attr('id', 'input_text_'+i);
  );

  var $select = $('<select>', select_attr).attr('id', 'input_select_'+i);

  $.each(options, function(key, value) {
     $select.append($('<option>', { text: value, value: value }));
  })

  $("#anotherobject_" + i).append($select);

}
```